# View products button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have trawled the internet over the past few hours to find out the best way to add a view product button to my website.
I have seen it done via a Bootstrap Modal but i don't want a modal, i want the product to display on a fresh page (Products.php).

i have created a button to view the products, and started to code an Ajax call

```
function productdetails(id){
var data = {"id":id};
jQuery.ajax({
  url : 'products.php',
  method : "post",
  data : data,
  success : function(data){
    jQuery('body').append(data);

  },
  error : function(){
    alert("Something went wrong!");
  }
});
}
```

but i know with a modal you need to add:

```
  JQuery('#modalname').modal ('toggle')
```

Anybody got any suggestions, as it seems all websites are using this method of a new page for product details rather than a modal.

Comment: and i am new to all this ajax, php javascript,

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the browser to the products.php page?

Comment: well my plan is to have a "view" product" button next to each search result, and allowing the user to click on the button to go to products.php where the details of the product will be displayed, like tech details etc

Comment: Why cant you use `<a href="#"></a>`?

Comment: this is currently what i have for the button 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="btndisplay">Details</button>
i dont want a static link, i want the user to be able to click on any product that's returned in the search and display the data relating to that product only

Comment: So if i understand correctly, youre able to get the contents of the page but want to replace all the content on the current page?

Comment: i have a page called Category.php which is displayed from the nav bar, i can search items in the db via price and brand, but the products are only thumbnail details - like short title and price, with an image, so i want to click the button "view Details" and it takes the user to a full new page (products.php) where they can view details like technical, other images.

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the page content or just replwcing the current content?

Comment: i can see basic content as explained above, its just i dont understand how when i click the button, to get the id of the product being displayed in the search results, to display on products.php page. get me?
sorry if i am not explaining myself properly

Comment: Alright i understand now, do you have any php code which uses the data sent i could see?

Comment: this is my filters section that users can filter by price and brand

  $cat_id = ((isset($_REQUEST['cat']))?sanitize($_REQUEST['cat']):'');
  $price_sort = ((isset($_REQUEST['price_sort']))?sanitize($_REQUEST['price_sort']):'');
  $min_price = ((isset($_REQUEST['min_price']))?sanitize($_REQUEST['min_price']):'');
  $max_price = ((isset($_REQUEST['max_price']))?sanitize($_REQUEST['max_price']):'');
  $b = ((isset($_REQUEST['brand']))?sanitize($_REQUEST['brand']):'');
  $brandQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM brand ORDER BY brand");

Comment: this is my button for updating the products with the filtered options
    <input type="submit" value=" Update " class="btn btn-xs btn-primary updatefilterbtn">

Comment: this is my php to display products on category.php page
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productsQuery)) : ?>
        <div class="item  col-xs-3 col-lg-3 productDetails">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <?php $photos = explode(',',$product['image']); ?>
                <img src="<?= $photos[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>" class="group list-group-image" style="wdith:100px; height: 200px;"/>

Comment: continued
 <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        <?php echo $product['title']; ?></h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        <?php echo $product['title']; ?></p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">

Comment: continued <span class="was"><span class="smaller">£</span><?php echo $product['list_price']; ?></span>

Comment: continued <span class="smaller">£</span><?php echo $product['price']; ?><span class="vat-text">&nbsp;inc. VAT</span></p>
                        </div>

Comment: contiued:             <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="btndisplay">Details</button>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 btnaddtocart">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: What code validates the id sent by your js?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories = '$cat_id'";
      $productsQuery = $db->query($sql);
      $category = get_category($cat_id);

Comment: so i use $productquery variable in a while loop to go through the $sql and find the products relating to which parent category

Comment: Here is where I'm confused: You have sent this to the php `var data = {"id":id};` then you get `cat_id` from `$_REQUEST['cat_id']` then send that to mysql. Aren't you trying to get `$_REQUEST['id']`?

Comment: my thought is with var data = id, i used that to get the id of the product that the "view products" button is linked to (if that makes sense), 
the cat_id is used to grab the ID of the parent category in the nav, so if they select components>cases, all cases display, that bit is fine. its just getting a button to allow the user to view the product (i.e cases) in full.. lets start over, what method would you use to do this?

Comment: if i had to guess id say i need to get the child id of the product displayed, then gather the information and display in products.php page?

Comment: It seems like you're over complicating this, why not have a page that when you send the js request returns all the html you need to do this, then in js just replace the nodes you already have with the nodes returned from the function.

Comment: ok, any suggestion of code to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sent to the page with the code you want to display lets just call it product.php for example.

```
function productdetails(id){
    var data = {"id":id};
    jQuery.ajax({
      url : 'products.php',
      method : "post",
      data : data,
      success : function(data){
        jQuery('body').append(data);

      },
      error : function(){
        alert("Something went wrong!");
      }
    });
    }
```

product.php might look something like this

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$results = mysql_query('get information');
?>

<html>
   <examplenode>
       <?php echo $results['product_title']; ?>
   </examplenode>
</html>
```

^ Above is what the js will get when the request is sent, then just replace the the current html

```
$('body').replace(data);
```

Comment: ok i added:

      $id = sanitize($_POST['id']);
      $id = (int)$id;
      $results = $db->query($sql); (i dont have the sql statement on products.php page, you think i need it? will look like this - $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'"; 

in my html content i added:
<?= $results['title']; ?>

got these errors?
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.alphacomponents.co.uk\products.php on line 6
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.alphacomponents.co.uk\products.php on line 21

line 21 is html content

Comment: also added:
function productdetails(id){
    var data = {"id":id};
    jQuery.ajax({
      url : 'products.php',
      method : "post",
      data : data,
      success : function(data){
        jQuery('body').replace(data);

      },
      error : function(){
        alert("Something went wrong!");
      }
  });
  }

to my footer

Comment: my php is:
$id = sanitize($_POST['id']);
      $id = (int)$id;
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
      $results = $db->query($sql);
      $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

and html - <?= $product['title']; ?>,

the only error is: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.alphacomponents.co.uk\products.php on line 6 i dont understand this error as i am declaring the index of id here: 

$id = sanitize($_POST['id']);
      $id = (int)$id;

Comment: Did you use `$db->query()` specifically in your code?

Comment: yeah in products.php page, in the php section at the top of the page:

    $id = sanitize($_POST['id']);
      $id = (int)$id;
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
      $results = $db->query($sql);
      $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have put that, `$db->query()` is from a library you'll need to use `mysql_query()` that is probably what is causing the error

Comment: i am still getting the Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.alphacomponents.co.uk\products.php on line 12

i am confused as to why its appearing, 

i have done a trigger_error($db->error); to see if the SQL statement is working and it comes back with no errors.